# can't pickle listreverseiterator objects using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle, apache-spark-mllib

I'm quite new to python. The following code has some serialization problems:

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
import random
data = sc.parallelize([range(100),range(100),random.sample(range(100),100),reversed(range(100))])
print(Statistics.corr(data))
```

I'm getting:

> TypeError: can't pickle listreverseiterator objects

So "reversed" seems to create a non-serializeable object - any idea how to cope with this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
reversed(range(100))
```

with

```
list(reversed(range(100)))
```